# Python3 type hint for operator module

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, type-hinting

How can I write a type hint for an argument that should be an operator function? For example, see this function:

```
import operator
from typing import Dict, Tuple

def func(thresholds: Dict[str, Tuple[operator, float]] = None):
    if thresholds is None:
        thresholds = {"height": (operator.lt, 0.7), "width": (operator.gt, 0.1)}
    pass
```

When I try to run my code I get:

```
TypeError: Tuple[t0, t1, ...]: each t must be a type. Got <module 'operator' from ...>.
```

Edit: I realize that operator is a module, not a type, and that the argument I'm looking for is a function from that module. I'm trying to see if there's any way to let the user know that I expect an operator function as the argument. Is the only way to explain in a docstring?

Comment: "that should be an operator function" That isn't a type. You just want to type hint some binary function, look at `Callable`, so probably `Callable[[float], float]`.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using a mutable dict container as the default value for a function.

Comment: @flakes well, you shouldn't if you don't understand the semantics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`operator` is a module, not a class or type. What you want to do is make a typehint that can satisfy the functions being passes to `func`. If we were to write `operator.lt` from scratch, it would probably look like this:

```
from numbers import Number

def le(a: Number, b: Number) -> bool:
    ...
```

Using the `Callable` type we can write this as:

```
Callable[[Number, Number], bool]
```

Putting that altogether you would get something like this:

```
import operator
from typing import Dict, Tuple, Callable, Optional
from numbers import Number


Operator = Callable[[Number, Number], bool]
OperatorDict = Dict[str, Tuple[Operator, float]]


def func(thresholds: Optional[OperatorDict] = None) -> None:
    if thresholds is None:
        thresholds = {"height": (operator.lt, 0.7), "width": (operator.gt, 0.1)}
    pass
```